# Proving the Stability conditions in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, stability

The stability condition derived in Kardan's Statistical Mechanics textbook given by
$$\delta S\delta T+\delta J\delta X+\delta \mu \delta N\geq0$$
I'm trying to show from this
$$\partial^2_S E|_V\geq 0,\ \ \ \ \partial^2_V E|_S\geq 0\\ \partial^2_T F|_V\leq 0,\ \ \ \ \partial^2_V F|_T\geq 0\\ \partial^2_T H|_P\geq 0,\ \ \ \ \partial^2_P H|_S\leq 0\\ \partial^2_T G|_P\leq 0,\ \ \ \ \partial^2_P G|_T\leq 0\\$$

$\delta N=0$ throughout.

---

To prove, I started by assuming $J=-p$ and $X=V$
$$\delta S\delta T-\delta p\delta \geq 0V$$
and then
$$T=T(S,V)\ \ \ \&\ \ \ p=p(S,V)$$
Putting the differentials, We get

$$\delta S(\partial_V T|_S\delta V+\partial_S T|_V \delta S)-\delta V(\partial_V p|_S\delta V+\partial_S p|_V\delta S)\geq 0\\
\partial_S T|_V (\delta S)^2 - \partial_V p|_S (\delta V)^2 +\delta S\delta V(\partial_V T|_S-\partial_S p|_V)\geq 0$$
If we can get rid of from last term, We can prove the inequality that is asked but we can't because from the maxwell's relations
$$\partial_V T|_S=-\partial_S p|_V$$

---

Can you point out what I have done wrong? I noted that if I take $\delta J\delta X=\delta p\delta V$ then I can prove the relation but then I would have problem in proving other relations. What is the way out?

Comment: I do not understand what is your question. Isn't your last inequality enough to give the sign of the coefficients of the $(\delta S)^2$ and $(\delta V)^2$ terms?

Comment: @GiorgioP The inequality that I get in the last is of the form $a(\Delta x)^2+b(\Delta y)^2+c(\Delta x)(\Delta y)\geq 0$ How this is enough to find the sign of $a,b$? Since $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ can be arbitrary, and I think, the last term will cause trouble.

Comment: Just because they are arbitrary, the inequality must hold also for all the choices where one of them is zero. It is the reversed implication that requires an additional condition: $a \gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$ are not enough to have the correct inequality for the quadratic form.

Comment: @GiorgioP Yeah! That's right! Got it Thanks Is it possible to find a general condition?

Comment: Sure. Once obtained $a>0$ from the previous argument, you can multiply the inequality by $a$, keeping the $\ge 0$ condition. Then, if you add and subtract a term $c^2 (\Delta y)^2$, you get the inequality $(a \Delta x + c \Delta y)^2 +(ab -c^2) (\Delta y)^2 \ge 0$. Due to the arbitrariness of the increment, for any non-zero $\Delta y$ it is possible to find a $\Delta x$ which makes the first term zero and you get the final condition: $ab-c^2 \ge 0$.